# How to convert canoe test reports of CAPL into HTML report

Tags: html, capl

How to convert the file from Canoe CAPL report to HTML format?

I was tried in report viewer selector but no option i was found in it.

Comment: What do you mean by "CANoe CAPL report"?
In CANoe's global options, you can choose between _CANoe Test Report Viewer_ and _XML/HTML Format_.

Comment: If you run a test case, CANoe will automatically use one of its stylesheet to create an HTML report